# Unique Session ids in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I made a shopping cart model for a webapp that I am working on. It was just a standard ruby on rails model.

It lets users add products to the shoppingcart, but only shows it to them if they are the user that added the item. However, I'd like to let users who haven't signed in add items to a shopping cart.

Right now I'm using devise so I can check for a current_user, and assign that shopping cart item to that user. However is there a similar unique session id or anything I can use to simulate a user. So I only show the items that were added to the one person?

The reason for this is I'd like my user to go through as much of the ordering process as possible before asking them to sign-in and make an account.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to read [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sessions)

Answer (score 5):

A simple method for this is creating a shopping cart and then adding that identifier to the session regardless of their logged in state.

For example:

```
@shopping_cart = ShoppingCart.create(user: current_user)
session[:shopping_cart_id] = @shopping_cart.id
```

Later you can retrieve the current shopping cart, if any, as a `before_action` handler.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on similar problem. What I did was, I used `session_id`. First, you need a table(say, `product_list`) to hold the `product` list for temporary purpose. Populate each `product` to this table along with `session_id`. This will help you to identify the association of `product_list` with the `active user`. On checkout copy the record from `product_list` to your `shopping_cart` table and delete the record from `product_list`.

Try this, it might help you with the current problem.